# Single INSERT with multiple rows from multiple SELECT statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have multiple (> 100) PostgreSQL `INSERT` statements which all looks like this one, but with different selections:

```sql
INSERT INTO schema.table (geom, name, label, flag, type)
SELECT (geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, the_label, TRUE, type_id)
FROM abc.xzy a WHERE a.changelog = 1
ORDER BY a.num;
```

The SQL query may change but its output is done to fit the `INSERT` requirements, of course.

I'd like to do it all with a single `INSERT`. Maybe using the VALUES clause like:

```sql
INSERT INTO ... VALUES
  (val1,val2,val3,val4,...)
, (val11,val12,val13,val14,...)
```

This is shown to work [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert-multiple-rows/), with simple 'static' values (not from `SELECT` statements).

But it's not working with `SELECT` to fetch the values for the `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO schema.table (geom, name, label, flag, type)
VALUES
  (
    SELECT (geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, the_label, TRUE, type_id)
    FROM abc.xzy a WHERE a.changelog = 1
    ORDER BY a.num
  ),
  (
    SELECT (geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, a_label, FALSE, type_id)
    FROM def.uvt a WHERE a.typedf
    ORDER BY a.idx
  ),
...
);
```

I get an error: `subquery must return only one column` on the very first opening parenthesis, just before the very first `SELECT`.

How could I fix that, if possible?

PG version is >= 9.6.

Answer (score 1):

You attempt indicates confusion between *values* (fields) and *rows* (records).

You don't need a `VALUES` expression. Just use the `SELECT` statements directly. Chain multiple `SELECT` with `UNION ALL`:

```sql
INSERT INTO schema.table (geom, name, label, flag, type)
(
SELECT geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, the_label, TRUE, type_id
FROM   abc.xzy a WHERE a.changelog = 1
ORDER  BY a.num
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, a_label, FALSE, type_id
FROM   def.uvt a WHERE a.typedf
ORDER  BY a.idx
);
```

The extra parentheses are only needed to allow `ORDER BY` per `SELECT`. But that's only useful if the physical order of rows is relevant. (For performance optimization.) The order of inserted rows has no other significance and can change later with write operations. So you probably just want:

```sql
INSERT INTO schema.table (geom, name, label, flag, type)
SELECT geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, the_label, TRUE, type_id
FROM   abc.xzy a WHERE a.changelog = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT geom, <complicated string concatenation from multiple fields>, a_label, FALSE, type_id
FROM   def.uvt a WHERE a.typedf;
```